# In a perform, the code will not do math after displaying a line. (COBOL 85)

Tags: cobol, cobol85

Doing an amortization schedule. I have it set in the 300-REPORT module to display a line with payment information, then after the display to update that information as if another payment was made. It is supposed to stop at a balance of $0 then write it all to a text file.

Problem is, it displays the line, and instead of doing the new math, it just displays the same line over and over, therefore creating an endless loop.

```
300-REPORT.
      MOVE WS-BEGYEAR      TO WS-REP-YEAR
      MOVE WS-BEGMONTH     TO WS-REP-MO
      MOVE WS-PRINCIPAL    TO WS-REP-PRIN
      MOVE WS-INTEREST     TO WS-REP-INT                         
      MOVE WS-TERM         TO WS-REP-TERM

      COMPUTE WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M = WS-PRINCIPAL * (1+WS-INT-DEC)
      MOVE WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M   TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL
      MOVE WS-PRINCIPAL    TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M

      MOVE WS-PAYMENT-TOT  TO WS-REP-PAYMENT

      COMPUTE WS-INT-PAID-M = WS-PRINCIPAL * WS-INT-DEC
      MOVE WS-INT-PAID-M   TO WS-INT-PAID

      COMPUTE WS-CUR-PRIN-M                                                                                               
          = WS-PRINCIPAL - (WS-PAYMENT-TOT - WS-INT-PAID-M)                  
      MOVE WS-CUR-PRIN-M   TO WS-CUR-PRIN

      COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - WS-PAYMENT-TOT
      MOVE WS-END-BAL-M   TO WS-END-BAL

      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-TITLE3
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-TITLE4
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-LINE
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-PRIN-LINE
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-INT-LINE
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-TERM-LINE
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-LINE
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-HEADERS
      WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-HEADER-SEP.

      PERFORM UNTIL WS-END-BAL-M IS <= 0

          WRITE OF-LINE        FROM WS-REP-DATA-LINE
          DISPLAY WS-REP-DATA-LINE
          ADD 1 TO WS-PMT-NUM
          ADD 1 TO WS-REP-MO
          IF WS-REP-MO = 13
             ADD 1   TO WS-REP-YEAR         
             MOVE 01 TO WS-REP-MO                          
          END-IF
          MOVE WS-END-BAL TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL

          COMPUTE WS-INT-PAID-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M * WS-INT-DEC
          MOVE WS-INT-PAID-M  TO WS-INT-PAID

          COMPUTE WS-CUR-PRIN-M = 
          WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - (WS-PAYMENT-TOT - WS-INT-PAID-M)
          MOVE WS-CUR-PRIN-M  TO WS-CUR-PRIN

          COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - WS-PAYMENT-TOT
          MOVE WS-END-BAL-M   TO WS-END-BAL

      END-PERFORM
```

Comment: I refuse to even _read_ this until you narrow down the problem to the smallest piece of code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I suggest you either use a debugger, or use some other technique to display `WS-END-BAL-M` within the `PERFORM UNTIL` loop. I suspect that it never gets to be `<= 0`. Also, FYI, even back in Ancient Days (COBOL-74), they taught us to indent code for readability. Surely you could do the same.

Comment: What is the value of WS-PAYMENT-TOT ???, if it is zero you will have an infinite loop. Put some displays in to find out what the various values are.

Comment: Is WS-END-BAL-M a signed field?  The simplest thing is to do what John Saunders indicated, add a DISPLAY for WS-END-BAL-M.

Comment: I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I guess WS-PAYMENT-TOT is equal to zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You problem (perhaps not the only one) is here:

```
COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - WS-PAYMENT-TOT
```

Neither WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M nor WS-PAYMENT-TOT are changed within the loop, so the answer is always going to be the same, and the loop can never terminate.

You can make things easier for yourself by naming things better, paying attention to how things are coded and by using things which more naturally represent what you are doing. For instance:

```
  COMPUTE WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M = WS-PRINCIPAL * (1+WS-INT-DEC)
  MOVE WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M   TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL
  MOVE WS-PRINCIPAL    TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M
```

Is better as

```
  COMPUTE WS-REP-BEG-BAL = WS-PRINCIPAL * ( 1 + WS-INT-DEC)
  MOVE WS-PRINCIPAL    TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M
```

This are very similarly named, without the reader having a full clue as to what is what:

```
WS-END-BAL-M 
WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M 
WS-REP-BEG-BAL
WS-END-BAL
```

Especially when you do things like this:

```
MOVE WS-END-BAL TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL
```

Also:

```
SUBTRACT this-monthly-amount FROM outstanding-amount
```

Is easier to understand as to its purpose than:

```
COMPUTE this-monthly-amount = this-monthly-amount - outstanding-amount
```

Especially when scattered amongst `COMPUTE`s doing other things.

Combine all of the above, and you have a piece of code which is very difficult to understand at a glance.

The "shortest code to reproduce" has two intents: firstly, you may find the problem yourself whilst doing it; secondly, it helps for anyone else looking at the problem.

You have a Big Fat Loop, so what is important is the condition which controls the loop. Remove everything except what affects the starting value and how the value gets modified. It is important to also include the data definitions. On occasion you will have something which needs to be signed, but isn't.

WS-PAYMENT-TOT is not a target field in 300-REPORT. Its value is determined elsewhere. As was pointed out in the comments by @Julien Mousset, if that is ever zero, and that is all that ever affects your decrement in the loop, then you will have another Big Fat Loop. So we need to see the definition, and where WS-PAYMENT-TOT is set, and whether the PERFORM of 300-REPORT is conditional on it being non-zero.

Similar with WS-PRINCIPAL which is the source of WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M.

Now take out everything which is not to do with the control of the loop.

```
300-REPORT.

      MOVE WS-PRINCIPAL    TO WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M

      COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - WS-PAYMENT-TOT

      PERFORM UNTIL WS-END-BAL-M IS <= 0

          DISPLAY "Here we are in BFL"

          COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M - WS-PAYMENT-TOT

      END-PERFORM
```

We can even normalise that to use WS-PRINCIPAL in place of WS-REP-BEG-BAL-M.

```
300-REPORT.

      COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-PRINCIPAL - WS-PAYMENT-TOT

      PERFORM UNTIL WS-END-BAL-M IS <= 0

          DISPLAY "Here we are in BFL"

          COMPUTE WS-END-BAL-M = WS-PRINCIPAL - WS-PAYMENT-TOT

      END-PERFORM
```

In producing the "shortest code to reproduce" you can see that the calculation within the loop is the calculation for the initial value of the loop. If WS-PRINCIPAL were to be zero, the loop would never be entered. If WS-PRINCIPAL = WS-PAYMENT-TOT, the loop would never be entered. For all other situations, the loop will BFL.

You also have your structure backwards.

It is not a good idea to set things up "for next time". It means you are doing unnecessary work, confusing the reader, and making it difficult to maintain the program as it is unclear when fields can have processing safely changed.

Write out all the lines first.

In your loop, do all the work for the subsequent detail lines (if there are any) and write it out at as the last thing in the loop.

You have no "pagination" logic. If you have more than number-of-lines-on-page of detail lines, it is going to look ugly, even if only one "whatever" is printed per execution of the program.

Something like this:

```
      ADD 1 TO WS-REP-MO
      IF WS-REP-MO = 13
         ADD 1   TO WS-REP-YEAR         
         MOVE 01 TO WS-REP-MO                          
      END-IF
```

Is better as:

```
      IF WS-REP-MO = 12
         ADD 1   TO WS-REP-YEAR         
         MOVE 1  TO WS-REP-MO                          
      ELSE
         ADD 1   TO WS-REP-MO
      END-IF
```

Now WS-REP-MO never becomes logically invalid.

Even better, with an 88 on WS-REP-MO:

```
      IF WS-REP-PREV-MONTH-WAS-DECEMBER
          ADD 1   TO WS-REP-YEAR         
          MOVE 1  TO WS-REP-MO                          
      ELSE
          ADD 1   TO WS-REP-MO
      END-IF
```

Now at is more obvious what you are doing, and why.

Where you have code that is the same, put it in a paragraph (or SECTION if you are using those) and PERFORM it. When the code needs to change, you only have one place to change it. Give the paragraph a good name, and you can start to "read" the program.

You are likely a beginner with COBOL. If you just "patch it up" as you go along, you will end up with a horrible program which is difficult to follow, difficult maintain.

Don't be afraid to start again. If possible, start with a good working program which produces a report and which has the pagination in it. Then put in your high-level logic and once that is proved, move on down.

We used to design programs with pencil and paper (usually on the back of an old program listing) we run through the design, with pencil, paper and brain. Then transfer the design to a "skeleton" program which does the basics of what we wanted. Add the details, from high to low. At each stage we "desk-check" which means you look through the code again, pencil, paper and brain.

You then use the compiler to spot the typos. Fix those. Get a clean compile, and you've already done a lot of the stuff to get your program working.

Doing this you'll miss out on those "oh rats!" moments when you discover after writing the code that you have to make major changes.

With experience, you get to do all of that process in your head.

These days you're sitting in front of a PC. I still recommend the "paper and pencil" route, even if you implement that with use of your PC.

If you just sit down and write a COBOL program, then patch it up as your testing fails, the results will not be good for anyone.

I now see that you posted the whole program originally.

You PERFORM 100- from within 100-. That is not good, even if you escape from getting another BFL (depends on compiler).

You are taking data from a screen, typed by a human. You *must* verify that.

Using freeformat layout does not exclude you from helping yourself and anyone else by using indentation.

When testing you must try very hard to break the program. Otherwise your user will break it first time out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your control logic that calls 300-REPORT, but depending on how you did it, your stray period could cause some unexpected behavior.  You might want to take that out:

```
WRITE OF-LINE       FROM WS-HEADER-SEP.
```

It isn't assured that it will cause issues, but it can.  As a rule, you only need periods after labels and at the very end of a paragraph in Cobol-85+ code.

Comment: That's good eyes, Joe, but absolutely no way this time that it will cause a problem, however 300-REPORT is entered. It's only within conditions that the strays can cause a problem. No way else.

Comment: Don't get me started on the ambiguity of paragraph exits, stray periods and the twisted things that can happen if one uses "perform thru" styles.  But yes, you are correct, it isn't the culprit even if 300-report was the exit paragraph of a perform thru, I just like to apply the broken-windows theory of code...

Comment: Yeah, good point. Inattention to such details indicates likelihood that they'll cause a problem at some time. I don't think @user1828341 is going to confess to anything anyway, just quietly moving on.